# Is it safe to type cast between UnicodeChar and Integer?

Tags: delphi, unicode, casting

In pre-2009 Delphi (ANSI land) you could use `Ord` and `Chr` to convert a character to a byte and vice versa. That was good, for example when you needed to operate a char as a byte:

```
var
  ch: char;
begin
  ch:= chr(ord(ch1) xor ord(ch2));
end;
```

Obviously, in newer Delphis chars are not a byte anymore but two. Is it safe then to do the type casting:

```
var
  ch: char;
begin
  ch:= Char(integer(ch1) xor integer(ch2));
end;
```

to obtain the same results? The tests I've done until now work fine even when using Cyrillic and Arabic characters, but you never know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to change anything at all. Carry on using `ord()` and `chr()` exactly as before. These work in exactly the same way with the new wide `char` type. Your first block of code is still the idiomatic way to write this in Unicode Delphi.

Although the documentation for [`chr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.Chr) and [`ord()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Ord) implies that these function use `Byte` as the integral type, don't believe the documentation. It is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I asked because (at least in Delphi 2010) highlighting chr with the mouse shows the tooltip: returns System.AnsiChar, and when enetering the argument the tooltip says it expects a byte). But you are right, it seems to eat higher values than a byte and gives out the right character.

Comment: So the integral type is `Word` for Char and WideChar, but `Byte` for AnsiChar?

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Yes, that's my belief. It would be very nice if the documentation would catch up.